# Show that for every $m > 1$, there is an $n > m$ so that $a_m^m$ divides $a_n^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recurrence-relations, divisibility

> Define the sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ as follows. $a_1$ and $a_2$ are coprime positive integers and $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}a_n+1$. Show that for every $m > 1$, there is an $n > m$ so that $a_m^m$ divides $a_n^n$. Must $a_1$ divide $a_n^n$ for some $n > 1$?

> In the solution below, why must the first period begin at an index $s > i$? Also, from their counterexample, it seems that it's possible that $u_s = u_{s+t}$ is zero (i.e. not all the $a_n$'s are coprime)? So if the solution is wrong, how can it be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the first question : "why must the first period begin at an index $s \gt i$" ? Take $s$ to be the smallest index at which periodicity starts. The goal is to show that $s\leq i$, and it is therefore assumed (by contradiction) that $s\gt i$.

Answer to the second question : "from their counterexample, it seems that it's possible that $u_s = u_{s+t}$ is zero"

This is only possible when $s\leq i$. Because if $u_s=0$, then $u_{s+1}=1$, and for the same reason $u_i=0,u_{i+1}=1$. But then, by induction, we have $u_{s+2}=u_{i+2},u_{s+3}=u_{i+3}$ etc. This shows that periodicity has already started at index $i$, or in other words $s\leq i$.

Note that in the "counterexample" given, we have $s=i=1$.

So there is nothing wrong in the solution, no fix is needed.